# Helper methods in C++ and their visibility

Tags: c++

I have a function which performs calculations and I would like to be able to call this function from anywhere in my program. I know that in Java, I would just create a `public static` method within a class.

So far in C++ I have created a `namespace` for my particular function. The problem I am having is that this function uses its own helper functions. I would like these lower level functions to be non-visible (i.e. private) but am not sure how to do so.

So far, I have this code:

```
namespace HelperCalc{

    int factorial(int n){
         return n <= 1 ? 1 : n*factorial(n-1);
    }

    double getProbability(int x, int y){
        .....//do maths
        .... = factorial(x);
    }
}
```

So for example, I would to be able to call `getProbability()`, but I would like to 'hide' `factorial()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an anonymous namespace (within a source file, not a header):

```
namespace {
    int factorial(int n){
         return n <= 1 ? 1 : n*factorial(n-1);
    }
}

namespace HelperCalc{
    double getProbability(int x, int y){
        .....//do maths
        .... = factorial(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just asking... is this in any way better than just defining the functions in the source file, without the namespace?

Comment: Yes, because if you declare them without the anonymous namespace they're still accessible to other translation units/source files if they simply declare the function. No other translation unit has access to functions in an anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Separate the declaration and definitions of the functions you want to be public.
In the implementation file define the public functions and the helper functions.

`namespace.h`:

```
namespace X
{
    void public_function();
}
```

`namespace.cpp`:

```
// An anonymous namespace means functions defined within it
// are only available to other functions in the same source file.
namespace {
    void helper_function()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

namespace X
{
    void public_function()
    {
        helper_function();
    }
}
```